# Skip ordered list item numbering

Tags: html, css, list, html-lists

I have an ordered list and I'd like to skip the number output from a particular item.

Traditional output:

```
1. List item
2. List item
3. List item
4. List item
5. List item
```

Desired output:

```
1. List item
2. List item
   Skipped list item
3. List item
4. List item
5. List item
```

Is this achievable in CSS? I discovered an [`<ol>` "start" attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_ol_start.asp) that I didn't know about before, but doesn't seem to help me.

Comment: Do you really want to skip that item, or is it more like a child or an additional line of the item before it?

Comment: Yes, I just want to skip this item but retain the rest of the numbering. It's for track listings, that can be split into multiple sections within one "disk". The track numbers need to ignore the section titles. I can't actually create separate sections with separate lists, since the numbering is for the tracks in the disk rather than each section. Let me know if that's not clear and you need a Fiddle.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Another option is to use CSS3 counters: **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/gPLwf/)**

HTML

```
<ul>
<li>One</li>
<li>Two</li>
<li class="skip">Skip</li>
<li>Three</li>
<li>Four</li>
</ul>​
```

CSS

```
ul {
    counter-reset:yourCounter;
}
ul li:not(.skip) {
    counter-increment:yourCounter;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li:not(.skip):before {
    content:counter(yourCounter) ".";
}
ul li.skip:before {
    content:"\a0\a0\a0"; /* some white-space... optional */
}
```

Comment: Yup, I was thinking this solution might be all that's possible. Good [article on 456 Berea Street](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/) about it. Thanks for the demo!

Comment: This has the unfortunate side effect of turning all `<ul>` elements into `<ol>` ones.

Comment: Also, using this method, you need to add additional styling to compensate that the list item will be placed over the numbers at some point.

Answer (score 30):

The simplest way is to remove the list marker from the item to be skipped and set the number of the next item using [the `value` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/lists.html#adef-value-LI) (which will not be deprecated/obsolete in HTML5). Example:

```
<ol>
<li>List item
<li>List item
<li style="list-style-type: none">List item
<li value=3>List item
<li>List item
</ol>
```

Comment: Very interesting. [Looks like](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp) this has good browser support too. Can't think of any down-side... surely there must one?!

Comment: Only downside I can see is this "value" attribute when dynamically generated. Would be nice if all handled within CSS (other than "skip" class) like previous solution.

Comment: Used this just now. Worked like a charm!

Comment: good but don't like the way you have to add `value=3` to set/correct the count. https://jsfiddle.net/1vew6e61/

Comment: XHTML Strict validation complains *there is no attribute "value"* :(

Answer (score 3):

Have to agree with everyone critizicing my previous "solution" as it seems, this is only possible with pseudo-selectors and then it doesn't matter whether you would use `ul` or `ol`. Giona's Solution is best.

---

*previous content:*

It's quite simple now.

Just add the following to a class .skip with .skip being used for the skipped list-item:

```
ol li.skip {
    list-style-type:none;
    counter-increment:none;
}
```

in HTML it would be:

```
<ol>
  <li>first list item</li>
  <li class="skip">2nd list item</li>
  <li>third list item</li>
</ol>
```

resulting in:

1. first list item
   2nd list item
2. third list item

Comment: Add an Example here too to elaborate

Comment: Hope it is elaborated enough

Comment: Yup brother ,the user won't have to test the script themselves and now the can implement it directly  :)

Comment: Doesnt work it shows different  result  ir show 1,3. this solution is wrong

Comment: worked for me and maybe better/shorter than Giona above https://jsfiddle.net/xuv342xb/

Comment: This looked like a nice, clean and elegant solution - except it didn't work in 3 versions of Firefox I tested.

Comment: Right! It's also exemplified in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/counter-increment

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution (only with CSS) that allow you to keep the normal usage of an li (list-item) from an ol (ordered list). That means all `li` item are consitent and there are no item that not represent the same thing as its neighbour.

Code just below :

```css
 .term-and-condition li {
    position: relative;
  }
  .term-and-condition ol ol {
    list-style-type: lower-latin;
  }
  .term-and-condition h2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.4em;
    left: -1.5em;
  }
  .term-and-condition h3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.4em;
    left: -1.5em;
  }
  .term-and-condition h2 + *,
  .term-and-condition h3 + * {
    margin-top: 4em;
  }
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Skip ordered list item numbering</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article class="term-and-condition">
      <h1>Participants agree to be bound by these Terms and Conditions</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <h2>The Promoter</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p>
        </li>

        <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p></li> 

        <li>
          <h2>Eligibility</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p>
        </li>

        <li>
          <h2>Entry</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p>
        </li>

        <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p></li>

        <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere, accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p> </li>

        <li>
          <p>Entrants must upload an image and text that:</p>
          <ol>
            <li><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, qui cupiditate fugit quo ipsa hic, in amet libero magnam consectetur facere</p></li>
            <li><p>consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis dolorum consequuntur,</p></li>
            <li><p>in amet libero magnam consectetur facere,</p></li>
            <li><p>accusantium sed, adipisci aliquam unde! Sit, iure.</p></li>
            <li>
              <h3>Additional requirements</h3>
              <p>All entries must be the participant’s own image or have the relevant permission</p>
            </li>
            <li><p>The entrant must be the lorem</p></li>
          </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
        <h2>Winner Selection</h2> 
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit tenetur minus dolores! Natus harum pariatur voluptas, voluptatibus magnam, animi explicabo eos laudantium delectus nobis repellat dicta eveniet, et blanditiis ducimus!</p>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

— [See the Codepen](http://codepen.io/Haeresis/pen/Lkhrf)

Comment: I wouldn't prefer this solution since its too much work when it comes to responsive design or when used bootstrap ( changing top and left margin/padding)

Comment: That's is not true. This is fully responsive and compatible along a Bootsrap usage.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I tried that seemed to work was just adding a font-size: 0.  This could be applied to the aforementioned "skip" class.

Admittedly, this solution lacks some HTML purity, but is quite simple.