# How to place different width and height images aside with ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Please see the image.
Basically I want to make ordered lists. And I want to insert images sometimes right sometimes left with the ordered lists.

It's like a article with different width and height images. But with ordered list. If it would with paragraph I have no problem. But I am stuck with ordered list.

Can anyone help me? 
 [image: see image]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! please try to be more specific and show some search or some trials that you have made I recommend to read how to ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask at least you have to post your code to allow community to help out!

Comment: Please add some information and "code" on what you already tried to solve the problem, so we can help you at all.

Comment: How can I edit my post?

Comment: under your question directly you should find your tags and then under tags you should see 3 options to share,edit or delete your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT :

[Here's the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/20v2ty3n/4/)

These lines means you remove default list-style of the list and with before property, you can count number of `<li>` elements and style it independantly of the text

```
ol { 
    counter-reset: item;
    list-style-type: none;
}
li { display: block; position: relative; }
li:before { 
    content: counter(item) "  "; 
    counter-increment: item;
    position :absolute; 
    left: -30px; top: 0; font-size: 28px;
}
```

See this post as @afelixj said : 
[Skip ordered list item numbering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858130/skip-ordered-list-item-numbering)

Comment: I tried to make that. I used img inside ol. I don't know it is right to do or not. Can you take a look at this? jsfiddle.net/20v2ty3n

Comment: Thanks buddy. It works :) 
But is it a good coding to insert img inside ol/ul?

Comment: That is not a valid html

Comment: It's better to insert <img> into <li> tag like this : <li><img/></li>

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

```
ol li {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

**Option 2:**

Add `float:left;` to your `ol`

If you find elements after this are floating when you don't want them to, insert a new `div` to clear the float property:
`<div style="clear: left;" />`

If you only want to do this on a specific class or ID you can do this, for example:

```
.myclass {
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Without seeing your exact code it's hard to give you a definitive answer, but one of these options will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You can try below method using unordered list, and adding number using method mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858130/skip-ordered-list-item-numbering)..

Images are also added in `li`, with a class `skip`. and add class left or right to add `float:left;` and `float:right;`

```css
ul {
   counter-reset:yourCounter;
   list-style:none;
}
li{
  padding-left: 40px;
  margin: 0 0 20px;
}
li:before{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -40px;
  font-size: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
ul li:not(.skip) {
counter-increment:yourCounter;
}
ul li:not(.skip):before {
content:counter(yourCounter);
}
ul li.skip:before {
content:"";
}
li.right{
  float: right;
  clear: right;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sequi laudantium, nihil molestiae non fugit, delectus dolores veritatis illum est explicabo eveniet quo eaque aut tempora, cumque minus nisi animi.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sequi laudantium, nihil molestiae non fugit, delectus dolores veritatis illum est explicabo eveniet quo eaque aut tempora, cumque minus nisi animi.</li>
<li class="skip right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250/nature/" alt=""></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sequi laudantium, nihil molestiae non fugit, delectus dolores veritatis illum est explicabo eveniet quo eaque aut tempora, cumque minus nisi animi.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sequi laudantium, nihil molestiae non fugit, delectus dolores veritatis illum est explicabo eveniet quo eaque aut tempora, cumque minus nisi animi.</li>
<li class="skip right"><img src="http://lorempixel.com/360/230/nature/" alt=""></li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sequi laudantium, nihil molestiae non fugit, delectus dolores veritatis illum est explicabo eveniet quo eaque aut tempora, cumque minus nisi animi.</li>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum sequi laudantium, nihil molestiae non fugit, delectus dolores veritatis illum est explicabo eveniet quo eaque aut tempora, cumque minus nisi animi.</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/07xe4p4x/2/